# HTTP response body is empty string

Tags: c#, http

I am working on a project that displays logs from workstations in a factory, the logs are saved on an SQL database and sent to a react application using a .NET based API.
The problem is that the response body sometimes reach 6-7 million objects with different properties (almost 1gb of data) and when I try to fetch such large response i get an empty string as a response.
when I test it with postman the app crashes. is there any way to fix this?

notes:
the page performance is not a priority for me.
it is important for me to get all the data.
when I try to get the first 10000 objects everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Usually while dealing with a lot of data, the approach of pagination is being preferred. You can use the **skip** and **take** variables to do the consecutive requests for fetching the data.

You can refer: https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/pagination-in-aspnet-core-webapi/